# Как захватить src="" у img через JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как захватить `src=""` у `<img class="img-val">`через JS и добавить его для `<li>` как атрибут `data-src=""`?
Пытался выполнить подобным кодом, но он берет `src=""` только у первой цепочки `li>div>div>img`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.piz').children().children()
  let src = $('.img-val').attr('src')
  $('.piz').attr('data-src', src)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="piz">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f" class="img-val">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="piz">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <img src="vk.com/vk.png" class="img-val">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Пройтись циклом по результату селектора?

Comment: @u_mulder буду благодарен, если расскажете, как это сделать. Только изучаю JS, не совсем все еще "устаканилось" в голове.

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: это в цикле надо сделать - обычный for или foreEach

Comment: @Qwertiy извините, забыл сказать, что полученный адрес изображения необходимо добавить для li атрибутом data-src=""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.piz').attr('data-src', function () {
    return $(this).find('.img-val').attr('src')
  })
  
  console.log($('ul')[0].outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="piz">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f" class="img-val">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="piz">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <img src="vk.com/vk.png" class="img-val">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('img').each(function(index, element) {
  console.log( index, element.src);
  $('li').attr('data-src', element.src);
  console.log($('li'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="piz">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f" class="img-val">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="piz">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <img src="vk.com/vk.png" class="img-val">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((element, index) => {
  console.log(element.src);
  document.querySelectorAll('li')[index].setAttribute('data-src', element.src);
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="piz">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f" class="img-val">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="piz">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <img src="vk.com/vk.png" class="img-val">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Air, подскажите, как теперь добавить полученный src=""  в data-src="" к каждому li

Comment: `closest` же, причём и в jquery, и в native. В цикле заново искать все и выбирать по индексу - это какая-то жесть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ты о чем?

Comment: @Air 1. `forEach` - это цикл - та на каждом `img` заново по всему документу ищешь одни и те же `li`. 2. Само по сее сопоставление по индексу вместо вложенности - так себе. 3. Есть же удобный метод `closest`.

Comment: Я тя понял... Благодарю...